# Google Analytics event code snippet not recognizing variable call

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to send an event action to Google Analytics by setting a variable: `sum`.

But I only see this event in my reports if I put `2 + 2` within quotation marks, but obviously the output will be `2 + 2` and not `4`.

Not working:

```
var sum = 2 + 2;
gtag('event', sum, {'event_category': 'Lead'});
```

Working, but not as expected:

```
var sum = '2 + 2';
gtag('event', sum, {'event_category': 'Lead'});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem on the Google Analytics side?